# How to do this step?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-probability

This is a slide from a Markov model lecture. I am studying probability in the context of Computer Science, namely, Markov models for traditional AI learning.

I got stuck following the conditional probability equations in the linked slide, when trying to work out the simplifications myself.

I tried to condition the inner 3 joint events using $(x_t | x_{t-1}, e_{1:t})$ but I couldn’t get it to the form shown.

$x_t$ is the Hidden Markov model state and $e_t$ is the observed effect.

***Q***: How do they do this conditional expectation simplification step? (see red lines I marked in slide image).

Thanks!

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeapX.jpg)

P.S. my rep not high enough to post image directly, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with the expression under the sum and 
using Markov property and rule of conditional probability:
$$
P(x_{t-1}, x_t, e_{1:t}) = 
P(x_{t-1}, x_t, e_1,e_2,...,e_t)=
P(x_{t-1}, e_{1:t-1}) P(x_t, e_t | x_{t-1}, e_{1:t-1})
= P(x_{t-1}, e_{1:t-1}) P(x_t|x_{t-1}, e_{1:t})P(e_t|x_t, x_{t-1},e_{1:t-1})
= P(x_{t-1}, e_{1:t-1})P(x_t|x_{t-1})P(e_t|x_t)
$$

Comment: upvoted! it won’t show until my rep increases to > 15 :(

Comment: Thanks, no worries though :)

Comment: Thanks :) One last thing: I have been staring at it for a while, but can’t see it.  I can derive P(a,b|c) = P(a|b,c)*P(b|c)  from P(a,b,c) just using Baye’s rules.  So then from your 2nd equality to 3rd equality simplification, your ‘a’ is xt, ‘b’ is e,t; then shouldn’t P(a,b|c) be P(xt | et, x,t-1, e,1:t-1) * P(e,t | x,t-1 , e, 1:t-1) — that is, how did you get the ‘extra’ xt in the conditioned events of P(e,t | x,t ,  x,t-1,  e,1:t-1 ) ???    You can flip it around and let a and b be reversed, but the same question remains... ??  Thanks so much for any kind help.

Comment: (1) No need for Bayes rule since $P(a,b|c) = P(a|c)P(b|a,c)$ in general. (2) $x_t$ is not 'extra', it has the same role as $a$ in (1).

Comment: Thanks for kind help again. I am just confused over that one little point, still:  but if ‘x,t’ plays the role of ‘a’ in (1), how did your ‘c’ = x,t-1 , e,1:t-1  change into c = x,t-1 , e,1:t  then?  (ie, an ‘extra’ e,t ??)

Comment: See now, it was a typo. Note that the question is on hold now and will likely be removed. Perhaps you can add a few words to the question, saying for example -- that you're studying probability and got stuck on a specific line . Then spell out  the math expressions using Mathjax -- you can just copy and paste from my answer (use 'edit' link')

Comment: Thanks !! That makes sense now. I have edited the question per your kind advice. Hopefully they will not delete it now.

Comment: OK, I edited the question a bit more (may not be visible to you). Let's see if it's accepted. I'm fairly new to the site myself and don't know yet how their rules work in practice.

Comment: Thanks for helping with the math equations =)